# double for loop that doesn't result enough number of lines

Tags: python

hello i'm new for python and have a little problem 
thank you in advance for solving this problem that i cannot understand :(

here's two files that i want to print on python shell

file 1 looks like this:

```
chr6    43547333,43547553   CTCF

chr6    43547100,43547500   TFTF

chr6    43547200,43547699   AAAA
```

and, file 2 looks like this:

```
1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547400    43547700    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547100    43547200    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,
```

and I tried tried python code like this

```
 ENCODE_edit = open("/media/jiyeonh/external/3.ENCODE/test_1.txt","r")
 ACTN1_raw = open("/media/jiyeonh/external/3.ENCODE/test_2.txt","r")
 for a in ENCODE_edit.readlines():
   print(a)
   for b in ACTN1_raw.readlines():
     print(b)
```

i expected

```
chr6    43547333,43547553   CTCF

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547400    43547700    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547100    43547200    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,


chr6    43547100,43547500   TFTF

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547400    43547700    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547100    43547200    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,


chr6    43547200,43547699   AAAA

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547400    43547700    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547100    43547200    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1
```

but my result was like this

```
chr6    43547333,43547553   CTCF

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547400    43547700    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,

1114    NR_073422   chr6    +   43547100    43547200    69454180    69454180    4   69446398,69446644,69452401,69454061,    69446501,69446904,69452518,69454180,    0   ACTN1-AS1   unk unk -1,-1,-1,-1,


chr6    43547100,43547500   TFTF

chr6    43547200,43547699   AAAA
```

View Result: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69oQD.png)

i cannot understand why it doesn't repeat the inner loop at the second and third loop

did i do something wrong?? :(

Comment: have you tried is with an easier structure? This looks strange, because as far as I can see, the code should return what you expect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
ENCODE_edit = open("/media/jiyeonh/external/3.ENCODE/test_1.txt","r")
for a in ENCODE_edit.readlines():
  print(a)
  ACTN1_raw = open("/media/jiyeonh/external/3.ENCODE/test_2.txt","r")
  for b in ACTN1_raw.readlines():
    print(b)
  ACTN1_raw.close()
```

readlines() read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read. So in your code, at the second time execution of outer loop, the ACTN1_raw.readlines() may at EOF and thats why dont return anything.

Comment: It works!!!! didn't even know what EOF means but learned it thanks to your kind explanation :) thank you so much